# Вызов метода одного из классов по параметру

Tags: java, android

Есть несколько классов (Character1, Character2...) реализующих интерфейс Actor. 
У всех есть метод jump(). Как вызвать jump() из Character2 с помощью параметра?

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен. Вам надо так: `Actor char2 = new Character2(); char2.jump();`?

Comment: param - параметр (сейчас равен 2, к примеру)
player - экземпляр какого-либо буферного класса реализующий логику вызова 

Необходимо чтоб:
player(param).jump();    был равен    Character2.jump();

Это только навскидку. Пока что только прикидываю оптимальную реализацию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам понадобится преобразование типов(нисходящее) и для удобства класс enum.
Создаете Actor person, а потом в зависимости от нужного вам класса создаете нужное, т.е.:

```
Actor person;
if(ActorType.CHARACTER1 == param) { //enum ActorType
    actor = new Character();
} else if(...) {
    ...
}
```

как-то так...